# How to send a process to multiple sinks in scalaz-stream

Tags: scala, scalaz, scalaz-stream

If I have a simple process which is emitting values of type `String` and I wish to send these to multiple sinks (i.e. each sink gets sent the `String`), how do I do this?

For example, running this program:

```
object Play extends App {

  def prepend(s: String): String => String = s ++ _
  val out1 = io.stdOutLines.map(prepend("1-") andThen _)
  val out2 = io.stdOutLines.map(prepend("2-") andThen _)

  val p = io.stdInLines to (out1 merge out2)
  p.run.run
}
```

The output looks like:

```
a     //input
1-a
b     //input
2-b
c     //input
2-c
d     //input
1-d
```

I want the output to be this:

```
a     //input
1-a
2-a
b     //input
2-b
1-b
c     //input
2-c
1-c
d     //input
1-d
2-d
```

---

**EDIT**

I can achieve this as follows:

```
implicit class ToBoth[O](p: Process[Task, O]) {
  def toBoth(s1: Sink[Task, O], s2: Sink[Task, O]): Process[Task, Unit] = {
    (for (o <- p; n <- Process.emit(o) ++ Process.emit(o)) yield n) to (s1 interleave s2)
  }
}
```

That is, I duplicate the input and interleave the output. This can be generalized:

```
def toAll(sinks: Sink[Task, O] *): Process[Task, Unit] = {
  (for (o <- p; n <- Process.emitAll(sinks.map(_ => o))) yield n) to sinks.reduceLeftOption(_ interleave _).getOrElse(Process.empty)
}
```

---

**EDIT 2**

I just realized that the generalization `toAll` does not work. `toBoth` does, though

Is there a better (built-in) way?

Comment: This is also one of my requirements and this is how I solved it: https://github.com/etorreborre/specs2/blob/specs2-three/common/src/main/scala/org/specs2/data/Fold.scala. The idea is to zip the 2 sinks into one: https://github.com/etorreborre/specs2/blob/specs2-three/common/src/main/scala/org/specs2/data/Fold.scala#L161

Comment: Sounds you counld implement the `sinks` as `channels`

Answer (score 3):

You could also use [`observe`](http://docs.typelevel.org/api/scalaz-stream/stable/latest/doc/index.html#scalaz.stream.Process$$ProcessSyntax@observe[F2[x]%3E:F[x]](f:scalaz.stream.Sink[F2,O]):scalaz.stream.Process[F2,O]) and `to` to attach multiple `Sink`s to a `Process`:

```
val p = io.stdInLines.observe(out1).to(out2)
```

`observe` is like `to` but echoes what is passed into the sink. So `io.stdInLines.observe(out1)` still emits the strings that come from stdin (that means it is of type `Process[Task, String]`) but also sends them to the sink `out1`.

---

As Eric pointed out, it is also possible to `zip` `Sink`s together. Here is a more elaborate example that sends individual lines of a logfile to different sinks depending on their log level:

```
sealed trait Loglevel
case object Info extends Loglevel
case object Debug extends Loglevel
case object Warning extends Loglevel

case class Line(level: Loglevel, line: String)

val outInfo = io.stdOutLines.contramap((l: Line) => "I: " + l.line)
val outDebug = io.stdOutLines.contramap((l: Line) => "D: " + l.line)
val outWarning = io.stdOutLines.contramap((l: Line) => "W: " + l.line)

val zipped = outInfo.zip(outDebug).zip(outWarning).map {
  case ((fInfo, fDebug), fWarning) =>
    (l: Line) => l.level match {
      case Info    => fInfo(l)
      case Debug   => fDebug(l)
      case Warning => fWarning(l)
    }
}

val lines = List(
  Line(Info, "Hello"),
  Line(Warning, "Oops"),
  Line(Debug, "ui ui"),
  Line(Info, "World"))

Process.emitAll(lines).liftIO.to(zipped).run.run
```

Running this will output:

```
I: Hello
W: Oops
D: ui ui
I: World
```

Comment: For reference: I opened an issue about how to make my last example nicer: https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz-stream/issues/289